# Не понимаю как выполнить алгоритм не хватает знаний синтаксиса

Tags: python

На вход программы подаются данные о результатах районной олимпиады. В первой строке – количество участников `N` (не более 100), а следующие `N` строк имеют следующий формат:

> <Фамилия> <Имя> <Баллы>

Здесь `<Фамилия>` – строка, состоящая не более чем из 20 символов; `<Имя>` – строка, состоя-щая не более чем из 15 символов; `<Баллы>` – целое число, обозначающее общее количество баллов, набранное участником. Все данные разделены пробелами. Пример входной строки:

> Петечкин Вася 152

На городскую олимпиаду проходят лучшие 25 участников (набравшие в сумме наибольшее количество баллов). Если другие участники набрали столько же баллов, что и участник, занявший 25-е место, они тоже приглашаются на городскую олимпиаду. Требуется вывести список участников,  прошедших на городскую олимпиаду, отсортировав его по фамилии (в алфавитном порядке).

Я понимаю как сделать если "отсечь фамилию и имя" и преобразовать строку (баллов) в число и после отсортировать. Но в конце проги нужно вывести именно С фамилией и именем, причем отсортировать по алфавиту, я не понимаю

```
N = int(input('Введите кол-во участников: '))
if N > 100:
    del N
else:
    print ('Введите фамилию,имя и баллы участника')
    peoples = [input () for i in range (N)]
    print (peoples)
    i_max = peoples.index ('250')


def quicksort (a):
    if len (a) < 2:
        return a
    pivot = a[i_max]
    less = [i for i in a[1:] if i < pivot]
    greater = [i for i in a[1:] if i >= pivot]
    return [pivot] + quicksort(greater)
```

Comment: Почитайте про [списки](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/spiski-list-funkcii-i-metody-spiskov.html) и [словари](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/slovari-dict-funkcii-i-metody-slovarej.html)

Comment: `peoples = [input().split() for i in range (N)]` -- чтобы получить список списков, где в подсписках будут фамилия, имя и баллы. После `peoples.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])` -- чтобы отсортировать список по фамилии

Comment: Если по я хочу отсортировать по баллам, то lambda x:x[2]